# Getting an empty list from webscraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and trying to scrape a real estate website. I am getting an empty list for the following query.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url="https://juddwhite.harcourts.com.au/Property/Rentals?location=8046&data=%7b%22locationOption%22%3a%7b%22value%22%3a8046%2c%22name%22%3a%5b%22Glen+Waverley%22%2c%22Melbourne+-+Eastern+Melbourne%22%2c%22Victoria%22%5d%7d%7d&page="

for page in range (1,4,1):
   
    r=requests.get(base_url+str(page))

    c=r.content

    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"search-item-content"})
    for item in all:
        for bond in item.find_all("div",{"class":"list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-sm-8"}):
            print(bond)
```

Could you guys please have a look?
Thank you.

Comment: There's no class named `list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-sm-8` on the page

Comment: I have gone inside one of the rental properties and did an inspect for the bond money which is under the class given in the code. <div class="list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-sm-8">
1,564</div>

Comment: Notice that once clicking on a 'card' on the page, the entire link changes. Please edit your'e question. Also,  read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help. I wanted to use the code to extract certain info that I am not getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get bond value from individual properties, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://juddwhite.harcourts.com.au/Property/Rentals?location=8046&data=%7b%22locationOption%22%3a%7b%22value%22%3a8046%2c%22name%22%3a%5b%22Glen+Waverley%22%2c%22Melbourne+-+Eastern+Melbourne%22%2c%22Victoria%22%5d%7d%7d&page={page}'

for page in range(1, 3):
    print('Getting page {}..'.format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser' )

    for a in soup.select('.search-item-container a'):
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://juddwhite.harcourts.com.au' + a['href']).content, 'html.parser')

        print(soup2.select_one('.hc-title').get_text(strip=True))
        print(soup2.find('span', text='Bond $: ').find_next('div').get_text(strip=True))
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Getting page 1..
Glen Waverley, 10 Snowden Drive VGW52967
1,955
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Glen Waverley, 1/2 Garrison Drive VGW52955
2,825
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Glen Waverley, 614/39 Kingsway VGW52953
1,739
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Glen Waverley, 40 Elmwood Crescent VGW52949
2,521
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Kuddos for trying something new :). Your code looks right. I did a simple search of the text "list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-sm-8" that you have in your for-loop, in the 'Inspect Element' option of that webpage, and it returned no results. Maybe you would want to check the exact attribute name you want to look for on your webpage. Hope this information helps.

Comment: I wanted to print the bond amount from every rental property. Hence, went inside one of the properties and did a quick inspect to find the bond amount is given  under the div class with list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-8. <div class="list-feature hc-text hc-grid-4 hc-grid-sm-8">
1,564</div>